# Cannot compile `enqueue_kernel` on opencl 2.1 NEO device

Tags: c++, opencl

I have the following code on the device `Intel(R) Gen9 HD Graphics NEO -- OpenCL 2.1 NEO` :

```
__kernel void update(
    const __global uint* positions,
    const __global float3* offsets, 
    const int size,
    __global int* cost

) {

    int global_id = get_global_id(0);

    if (global_id >= size) {
        return;
    }

    int3 update_index = position_from_index(grid_centroid_positions[global_id], SIZE) -
                        offset_grid;
    
    ndrange_t ndrange = ndrange_3d(size, size, size);

    enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), ndrange,
                           ^{update_surrouding_cells(offsets, global_id, update_index, update_edge_size, size, cost)});
}
```

But i get the following compiler error:

```
6:158:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ndrange_t'
    ndrange_t ndrange = ndrange_3d(size, size, size);
    ^
6:161:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'enqueue_kernel' is invalid in OpenCL
    enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), ndrange,
    ^
6:161:20: error: implicit declaration of function 'get_default_queue' is invalid in OpenCL
    enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), ndrange,
                   ^
6:162:163: error: expected ';' after expression
                           ^{update_surrouding_cells(offsets, global_id, update_index, update_edge_size, size, cost)});
                                                                                                                                                                  ^
                                                                                                                                                                  ;
6:161:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ndrange'
    enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), ndrange,
```

Compilation options are as follows:

```
-I "/home/development/cl" -g
 -D SIZE=256
```

The device supports opencl 2.1, yet when compiling it seems none of the things for enqueue_kernel exist. Do i need a special extension or something? I am reading the spec [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/pdf/OpenCL_C.pdf#page=152), but it doesn't seem to say anything about actually compiling the examples with dynamic parallelism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling, it is not just the version of the device that is important. The compiled version of cl code is passed into the compilation options. AKA the compilation options when compiling the opencl program (kernel code) should include:

```
-cl-std=CL2.0
```

Or the specific standard that you are looking for.

Comment: It might be worth clarify where to put these flags - either into the host compiler or the `clCompileProgram` calls.

Comment: @Quimby Thanks for the idea, if you know about opencl, check out my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72555582/enque-kernel-in-opencl-throws-clenqueuendrangekernel-exception-with-error-code, i could really use some help.

Comment: I used it few times, not sure I can help though. I highly recommend testing with two separate vendors, sometimes the code work on Intel and broke on NVIDIA and vice versa...the state was worse than OpenGL shaders sadly.

Comment: This doesn't work fully, if i try to copmpile with openCL 2.1, then it fails to compile in the same way. Even though these functions are supposed to be supported ...