# enque_kernel in opencl throws clEnqueueNDRangeKernel exception with error code -59 which should not occur

Tags: c++, opencl

I have the following simple test kernel:

```
kernel void check_run() {
    unsigned global_id = get_global_id(0); 
    queue_t q = get_default_queue();
    ndrange_t ndrange = ndrange_1D(1, 1);

    printf("Running my kernel %u\n", global_id)

    enqueue_kernel(q, CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_NO_WAIT, ndrange,
                ^{ size_t id = get_global_id(0);
                  printf("%zu\n", id); 
                } );
}
```

Which i compile on a `Intel(R) Gen9 HD Graphics NEO` with opencl 2.1 using the following build options:

```
-I "/home/development/cl" -g -cl-std=CL2.0 -cl-mad-enable
```

And launched from c++ like:

```
try {
    auto check_run = cl::KernelFunctor<>(cl::Kernel{program_, "check_run"});
    check_run(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, cl::NDRange(1)));
} catch (const cl::Error& e) {
    std::cout << "We should not have thrown in the profiling test.\n\n"
               << "cl error: " << e.err() << " name: " << e.what();
}
```

The code will compile and run, but throws the following:

```
cl error: -59 | what: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel
```

The error, according to [this](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2013-04-28/opencl-error-codes/) is:

> -59    CL_INVALID_OPERATION    - If interoperability is specified by setting CL_CONTEXT_ADAPTER_D3D9_KHR, CL_CONTEXT_ADAPTER_D3D9EX_KHR or CL_CONTEXT_ADAPTER_DXVA_KHR to a non-NULL value, and interoperability with another graphics API is also specified. (only if the cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing extension is supported).

But this makes no sense. I know that the error is thrown by the `enqueue_kernel` command because i have separated it all and if i comment out this line it runs fine. But according to the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/enqueue_kernel.html) this is not an error code that can be thrown by this function.

Any ideas?

Comment: To add to this, i added to the kernel: `uint group_size = get_kernel_work_group_size(^{} );` and it crashes the compiler ...

Comment: looks like this was to do with not having a device side queue, i will add an answer later.